# Weird result from $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

Tags: php, web-services, networking, ip, router

To log IP addresses of people visiting my web site I used `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

`192.168.111.111  18.04.2014 23:25:23` <- My local computer
`54.72.x.x        19.04.2014 10:05:53` <- Actual remote visitor, so this is working
`84.251.x.x       19.04.2014 12:41:38` <- ?

`84.251.x.x` is public address of my router. I cannot understand why that IP would have visited my website.

So why would `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` log this address? Documentation says it should show IP of user viewing page and as far as I understand router would not do such a thing.

My network consist of computer, web server (Raspberry Pi) and ZyXEL P-660HN-T1A router.

EDIT: I didn't do anything at 12:41 so that visit was not caused by me.

EDIT2: First I though this might have been problem with PHP `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` but I just managed to capture same event with Wireshark. It also shows HTTP query coming from `84.251.x.x`. I just can't understand why this happens.

Comment: This is correct behavior, because you are behind a router, your private IP address is just valid for you, while the router's public IP is the real one that visits the site.

Comment: Sorry, but that does not answer to my question. I understand difference between public and private IP and that is not case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating I finally found solution from packets captured by Wireshark:`User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (ABE, http://noscript.net/abe/wan)`

NoScript feature called ABE uses public address of routers.

http://noscript.net/abe/wan